# Redis wants to replicate with an unknown IP address

Tags: redis, replication

I developed a small application with a Redis datastore. I encounter no problems on my development machine. The application is built using docker images and defined in a docker-compose yml file.

I have deployed the project to a VPS. The environment is practically the same, it is built from the same docker images/Dockerfiles using the same docker-compose settings etc.

I noticed that once every few hours my Redis datastore is emptied. When digging in the logs I saw that Redis wants to replicate to a (for me) unknown IP address (based in Russia).

I have no clue what is happening. It looks like my server is compromised, which, of course, is possible. But it is a fresh install (ubuntu 18.04) with only my project on it. No unknown packages or other security risks. I have never encountered any kind of behavior like this except in malicious code.

When looking up the IP it wants to replicate to/from an in Russia hosted VPS. When visiting the IP I get a default Nginx page.

I have grepped my machine for the IP address but nothing found. I have exported the Docker image and grepped for that IP (also the ipv6) in the export but also nothing found.

I am clueless, does anyone have any idea what is happening here?

Here follows a snippet from the logfile.

```
1:M 13 Jul 2020 20:06:18.108 * Background saving terminated with success
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:20.873 * Before turning into a replica, using my own master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:20.873 * REPLICAOF 93.189.43.3:8886 enabled (user request from 'id=7746 addr=95.214.11.231:34714 fd=21 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=45 qbuf-free=32723 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof user=default')
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.620 * Connecting to MASTER 93.189.43.3:8886
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.621 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.667 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.714 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.807 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 9bdf2d313dc7387849d8607f14a5133e53b98cdf:1).
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.854 * Full resync from master: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ:1
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.855 * Discarding previously cached master state.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.855 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 55664 bytes from master to disk
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.949 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.949 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.949 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:21.950 # Failed trying to load the MASTER synchronization DB from disk
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:22.623 * Connecting to MASTER 93.189.43.3:8886
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:22.623 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:22.670 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:22.716 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Invalid argument'
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:23.625 * Connecting to MASTER 93.189.43.3:8886
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:23.626 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:23.672 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:23.719 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Invalid argument'
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:24.630 * Connecting to MASTER 93.189.43.3:8886
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:24.630 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:24.676 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:24.723 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Invalid argument'
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:25.633 * Connecting to MASTER 93.189.43.3:8886
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:25.634 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:25.680 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:25.727 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Invalid argument'
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:26.638 * Connecting to MASTER 93.189.43.3:8886
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:26.638 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:26.684 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:26.731 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Connection reset by peer'
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:27.641 * Connecting to MASTER 93.189.43.3:8886
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:27.642 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:27.720 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:27.800 # Error reply to PING from master: '-Reading from master: Connection reset by peer'
1:S 13 Jul 2020 20:06:28.077 # Module ./red2.so failed to load: It does not have execute permissions.
1:M 13 Jul 2020 20:06:28.179 # Setting secondary replication ID to 9bdf2d313dc7387849d8607f14a5133e53b98cdf, valid up to offset: 1. New replication ID is 17f925dc5b42b00af0083a1bb3502e6b68c2fc64
1:M 13 Jul 2020 20:06:28.179 * MASTER MODE enabled (user request from 'id=7746 addr=95.214.11.231:34714 fd=21 name= age=8 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=34 qbuf-free=32734 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof user=default')
```

Comment: Most likely your redis instance is open to public, which is very dangerous. So it's been attacked (very common also)Also, use a very long and complicated password for your redis server.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. See my reply at Pampy's answer. I think I was a bit naive with my whitelisting tactic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check if your Redis port is open to the internet?
If it is, you should close it as fast as possible and only make it available in your local network.

The replication might be initiated by someone connecting to your instance, that's why you don't find the remote IP on your server.

There are some known attacks using Redis, you can check the following thread for more information: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3594

Comment: 6379 is exposed via IP whitelisting. I am using the datacenters firewall, not the VPS at the moment. The only publicly exposed port is 22.

Looking at the information you linked I consider the VPS compromised and will do a full wipe and use the VPS firewall.

I also used ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=YES because I thought I could manage it via IP whitelisting. That was probably a bit naive on my side.

Thanks for thinking with me!